# C# String comparisons: Difference between CurrentCultureIgnoreCase and InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Tags: c#, string, comparison

When doing a string comparison in C#, what is the difference between doing a

```
string test = "testvalue";
test.Equals("TESTVALUE", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

and

```
string test = "testvalue";
test.Equals("TESTVALUE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

... and is it important to include that extra parameter, anyway?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Microsoft gives some decent guidance for when to use the `InvariantCulture` property:

[MSDN: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

> ... an application should use the
>   invariant culture only for processes
>   that require culture-independent
>   results, such as formatting and
>   parsing data that is persisted to a
>   file. In other cases, it produces
>   results that might be linguistically
>   incorrect or culturally inappropriate.
>
> **Security Considerations**
>
> If a security decision will be made
>   based on the result of a string
>   comparison or case change, your
>   application should use an ordinal
>   comparison that ignores case instead
>   of using InvariantCulture. [...]
>
> **String Operations**
>
> If your application needs to perform a
>   culture-sensitive string operation
>   that is not affected by the value of
>   CurrentCulture, it should use a method
>   that accepts a CultureInfo parameter.
>   [...]
>
> **Persisting Data**
>
> The InvariantCulture property is
>   useful for storing data that will not
>   be displayed directly to users.
>   Storing data in a culture-independent
>   format guarantees a known format that
>   does not change. When users from
>   different cultures access the data, it
>   can be formatted appropriately based
>   on specific user. [...]

Answer (score 40):

The other posts have given good advice, but I thought it might be nice to show an example of where it definitely makes a difference:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo turkish = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = turkish;                

        // In Turkey, "i" does odd things
        string lower = "i";
        string upper = "I";
        
        // Prints False
        Console.WriteLine(lower.Equals(upper, 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        // Prints True
        Console.WriteLine(lower.Equals(upper, 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

(There are no doubt many other cases - this was just the first one I thought of.)

Comment: Yes, the turkish i is a special case. They have a lowercase dotless "ı" with an uppercase "I", and a lowercase "i" with an uppercase "İ". It is considered the canonical case for culture differences.

Comment: For more on the nature of Turkish as the "canonical case" mentioned by configurator, see: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: I met the same thing in Vietnamese

`String.Compare("logid", "logId", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 1`. But `String.Compare("id", "Id", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0` :O