# C#: better way than to combine StartsWith and two ToUpperInvariant calls

Tags: c#

Somewhere in the back of my head a tiny voice is telling me "the C# code below smells".

```
private const string STR_ConnectionString = "ConnectionString";
private readonly string upperCaseConnectionString = STR_ConnectionString.ToUpperInvariant();
// a lot further on
string keyAttributeValue = keyAttribute.Value;
if (keyAttributeValue.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(upperCaseConnectionString)) 
{
    // some C# code handling a key that starts with "ConnectionString"
}
```

The constant `STR_ConnectionString` is used in other places in the code as well.

How to get rid of the smell?

Comment: Write extension method if such validation is too often in your code.

Comment: Does it smell good? or does it smell bad? looks ok to me :D

Comment: +1 @Shai I probably should have mentioned the original codebase is .NET 1.1, but it'll be .NET 4 soon so I've gone for the overload after the upgrade to .NET 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [overloaded StartsWith method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) taking a `StringComparison` enum value:

```
keyAttributeValue.StartsWith(STR_ConnectionString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) // or use StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase here
```

Comment: Accepted. I'm going for this solution. It's not in the .NET 1.1 FW that this codebase uses, but it is going to be .NET 4 soon anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`StartsWith` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) which supports case-insensitive matching:

```
if (keyAttributeValue.StartsWith(STR_ConnectionString, 
                                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    ...
}
```

It also makes your code more readable, because it expresses your intention: What you really want is a case-insensitive comparison, and that's what's written here. You don't really want "a case-sensitive comparison of values converted to upper-case"... that's just the workaround you use to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

If it smells bad because you're doing the ToUpper then the string compare, those can be combined using an overload of startswith:

```
STR_ConnectionString..StartsWith(upperCaseConnectionString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

However, it looks like you're rolling your own way to handle application configuration, which you shouldn't do. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: It's sort of an app configuration, but not quite, that I inherited from some teams that should have had a kick in the butt years ago :) You don't want to know how the rest of the inherited code looks like. Well maybe you do, but not all at once. Rest assured I'm going to do major refactoring work the upcoming months, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

There's always

```
keyAttributeValue.StartsWith(STR_ConnectionString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

but that will not perform as well as what you have. If you need to do it thousands of times per second, stick with what you have. If not, just do a case-insensitive match.

Also consider

```
keyAttributeValue.StartsWith(STR_ConnectionString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

which is faster and is probably what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an extension method that uses StringComparison to ignore case to deal with this in my projects.

```
public static string StartsWithIgnoreCase(this string value, string startsWith)
{
    return value.StartsWith(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

You can add null checks if you wish.

Comment: -1 Your extension method is just hiding which type of IgnoreCase you are using. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/417992/146513 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2007/06/29/string-equals-performance-comparison.aspx to know the difference and take that into account in each specific case.

Comment: @Protron I used `InvariantCulture` because OP used `ToUpperInvariant`.  You should always use the correct culture.  Thanks for the good links.

Comment: @cadrell0 I should have said that I think your answer is perfectly correct (for this particular case) if you take it outside the extension method. But I think is *dangerous* to put it in an extension method because many people will reuse that without knowing which culture are using. So I prefer to use the StartsWith the framework provides without extensions.