# What computer settings do I need to change to text string comparision in other languages

Tags: c#, string

C# WinForms: This program will be used in non-US-English countries too, so like Turkey. So I want to make sure if I do a string comparision I am doing it right for a client here in U.S and a client in Turkey. 
So I learned about the culture, CurrentCulture and InvariantCulture. But Now a little confused:

If I change the culture to Turkish like this and I want a Case Insensitive comparision too:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

Then This seems to be a good code. Do you agree?

```
string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

In this code strings like "istanbul" and "İstanbul" will be equal. But "istanbul" and "Istanbul" will Not be equal.

Comment: `Then this seems to be a good code. Do you agree?` That depends entirely on how you're using it.  You may or may not desire the behavior of that code; we have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417954/c-sharp-string-comparisons-difference-between-currentcultureignorecase-and-inva):

from one of the comments in the post:
"... the turkish i is a special case. They have a lowercase dotless "ı" with an uppercase "I", and a lowercase "i" with an uppercase "İ". It is considered the canonical case for culture differences."